# Defining two variables from one in Python

Tags: python, sql-server

I have a Python script where I am using PyODBC to send data to a server via POST request.  I have a column in my SQL server table that contains the values for two fields, and I need a Python or SQL expression to do so.  My two fields are resolution code and reason code.

All reason codes are numbers, i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 39, 54, 6, 7, etc.  All resolution codes are letters, i.e. A, B, C, RBI, Q, etc.

My SQL server column type which contains all values is a string.

The name of the column is RESOLUTION_CODE, but contains ReasonCodes as well.

What is a simple expression to say; `if RESOLUTION_CODE contains integer then RESOLUTION_CODE is reason code` while still maintaining my original RESOLUTION_CODE values, these are independent of each other, so where ever there is a row with a REASON there is no RESOLUTION and vice versa.

Example JSON Output where `39` is resolution but should be reason.

```
{
        "MetaData": {}, 
        "SRData": {
            "ListOfLa311MetalHouseholdAppliancesPickup": {
                "La311MetalHouseholdAppliancesPickup": [
                    {
                        "DriverFirstName": "sal", 
                        "DriverLastName": "Aguilar", 
                        "HouseholdItem": "None", 
                        "LastUpdatedBy": "SANSTAR1", 
                        "Name": "063020150920409621", 
                        "Type": "Metal/Household Appliances"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            "ReasonCode": " ", 
            "ResolutionCode": "B", 
            "SRNumber": "1-20541231"
        }
    }
]
[
    {
        "MetaData": {}, 
        "SRData": {
            "ListOfLa311MetalHouseholdAppliancesPickup": {
                "La311MetalHouseholdAppliancesPickup": [
                    {
                        "DriverFirstName": "SA", 
                        "DriverLastName": "Aguilar", 
                        "HouseholdItem": "None", 
                        "LastUpdatedBy": "SANSTAR1", 
                        "Name": "063020150550017771", 
                        "Type": "Metal/Household Appliances"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            "ReasonCode": " ", 
            "ResolutionCode": "RBI", 
            "SRNumber": "1-20529111"
        }
    }
]
[
    {
        "MetaData": {}, 
        "SRData": {
            "ListOfLa311MetalHouseholdAppliancesPickup": {
                "La311MetalHouseholdAppliancesPickup": [
                    {
                        "DriverFirstName": "sal", 
                        "DriverLastName": "Aguilar", 
                        "HouseholdItem": "None", 
                        "LastUpdatedBy": "SANSTAR1", 
                        "Name": "063020150919014731", 
                        "Type": "Metal/Household Appliances"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            "ReasonCode": " ", 
            "ResolutionCode": "A", 
            "SRNumber": "1-20538411"
        }
    }
]
[
    {
        "MetaData": {}, 
        "SRData": {
            "ListOfLa311MetalHouseholdAppliancesPickup": {
                "La311MetalHouseholdAppliancesPickup": [
                    {
                        "DriverFirstName": "SA", 
                        "DriverLastName": "Aguilar", 
                        "HouseholdItem": "None", 
                        "LastUpdatedBy": "SANSTAR1", 
                        "Name": "063020150856220561", 
                        "Type": "Metal/Household Appliances"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            "ReasonCode": " ", 
            "ResolutionCode": "39", 
            "SRNumber": "1-20539231"
        }
    }
]
[
    {
        "MetaData": {}, 
        "SRData": {
            "ListOfLa311MetalHouseholdAppliancesPickup": {
                "La311MetalHouseholdAppliancesPickup": [
                    {
                        "DriverFirstName": "sal", 
                        "DriverLastName": "Aguilar", 
                        "HouseholdItem": "Trash Compactor", 
                        "LastUpdatedBy": "SANSTAR1", 
                        "Name": "063020150857132911", 
                        "Type": "Metal/Household Appliances"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            "ReasonCode": " ", 
            "ResolutionCode": "A", 
            "SRNumber": "1-20539291"
        }
    }
```

Script Sample:

```
connstr = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=SVR;DATABASE=DB; UID=UID;PWD=PWD'

    conn = pyodbc.connect(connstr)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    FN_SRNumber = "SRNumber"
    lFields = [FN_SRNumber, "RESOLUTION_CODE", "ITEM_1","ITEM_2", "ITEM_3", "ITEM_4", "ITEM_5", "ITEM_6","ITEM_7","ITEM_8", "ITEM_9", "ITEM_10", "UID","last_edited_user"]
    #lFields = ["SRNumber"]
    sFields = ""
    for fld in lFields:
        if(sFields==""):
            sFields = fld
        else:
            sFields = sFields + "," + fld
    #List of the fields you'd like to exclude, like ItemCount for example.
    lFieldsExcluded = ["ITEM_1", "ITEM_2", "ITEM_3", "ITEM_4", "ITEM_5", "ITEM_6","ITEM_7","ITEM_8", "ITEM_9", "ITEM_10", "UID", "RESOLUTION_CODE", "last_edited_user"]

    #sSQL = "SELECT SRNumber FROM {}".format(pyFC)
    sSQL = "SELECT {} FROM {}  {}".format(sFields, pyFC, clauseSBE)
    print sSQL

    cursor.execute(sSQL)
    #columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
    columns = []
    for column in cursor.description:
        if not (column[0] in lFieldsExcluded):
            columns.append(column[0])

try:
    ii = 0
    white_item_1 = ""
    white_item_2 = ""
    white_item_3 = ""
    white_item_4 = ""
    white_item_5 = ""
    white_item_6 = ""
    white_item_7 = ""
    white_item_8 = ""
    white_item_9 = ""
    white_item_10 = ""
    rescode = ""
    reasoncode = " "
    ewaste_uid = ""
    last_edited_user = " "

    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        lResults = []    #make sure lResults are initiated here
        lValues = []
        for i in range(len(columns)):
            lValues.append( str(row[i]))
        white_item_1 = (str(row[lFields.index("ITEM_1")]))
        white_item_2 = (str(row[lFields.index("ITEM_2")]))
        white_item_3 = (str(row[lFields.index("ITEM_3")]))
        white_item_4 = (str(row[lFields.index("ITEM_4")]))
        white_item_5 = (str(row[lFields.index("ITEM_5")]))
        white_item_6= (str(row[lFields.index("ITEM_6")]))
        white_item_7 =(str(row[lFields.index("ITEM_7")]))
        white_item_8 = (str(row[lFields.index("ITEM_8")]))
        white_item_9 =(str(row[lFields.index("ITEM_9")]))
        white_item_10 = (str(row[lFields.index("ITEM_10")]))

        white_uid = (str(row[lFields.index("UID")]))
        rescode = (str(row[lFields.index("RESOLUTION_CODE")])

        last_edited_user = (str(row[lFields.index("last_edited_user")]))

        #dResult = dict(zip(columns, row))
        dResult = dict(zip(columns, lValues))


        dResult.setdefault("ReasonCode", reasoncode)
        dResult.setdefault("ResolutionCode",rescode )



   d = dict()
        d.setdefault("DriverFirstName",last_edited_user )
        d.setdefault("DriverLastName","Aguilar" )
        d.setdefault("LastUpdatedBy", "SANSTAR1")
        d.setdefault("HouseholdItem", white_item_1)
        d.setdefault("Type", "Metal/Household Appliances")
        d.setdefault("Name", white_uid )


        l311.append(d)
 dL311 = dict()
        dL311.setdefault("La311MetalHouseholdAppliancesPickup", l311)
        dResult.setdefault("ListOfLa311MetalHouseholdAppliancesPickup",dL311)
except:
    print "failed"
```

Comment: Are you generating that JSON output?  How are you doing the JSON output?  That can explain how you got `"39"` into `"ResolutionCode"`.

Comment: Well all of that is kind of irrelevant it was for more or less visualization purposes; like I said, the reason and resolution codes are in one column in my SQL table, I would like any code that has a number to be called reasoncode, but this is a string field.

Comment: Which is why I am asking you if you are generating the JSON output. If you are you can simply make it happen by additional logic.

Comment: Yes I am generating the JSON

Comment: Then please update the question to include the relevant python code snippet where the entries for `"ReasonCode"` and `"ResolutionCode"` are being constructed.

Comment: See edits, RESOLUTION_CODE is the column fetched, but it also contains my values for ReasonCode

Comment: Then isn't your solution simply: `if rescode.isdigit(): reasoncode = rescode`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `if` expression to achieve this, for example -

```
dResult.setdefault("ReasonCode", rescode if rescode.isdigit() else "")
dResult.setdefault("ResolutionCode",rescode if not rescode.isdigit() else "")
```

If you want to set empty string for the opposite case (that is if reasoncode is set, then resolution code to be set with empty string.